# Let $f$ be a continuous function on $R$ and suppose that $b(x)$ is ${C^1}$ function .Defined $G(x) = \int\limits_a^{b(x)} {f(t)dt} $. Compute $G'(x)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $R$ and suppose that $b(x)$ is ${C^1}$ function. Define $G(x) = \int\limits_a^{b(x)} {f(t)dt} $. Compute $G'(x)$

Sol.    Let  f be a continuous function on R
           b(x)  is ${C^1}$function
            F  is ${C^1}$function and $F' = f$. Which F defined $F(x) = \int\limits_a^{b(x)} {f(t)dt} $
          $G(x) = F(x) = \int\limits_a^{b(x)} {f(t)dt = F(b(x))} $
    Since b(x) is ${C^1}$function then $b'(x)$ exist. By THE CHAIN RULE
        $G'(x) = F'(b(x))b'(x) = f(b(x))b'(x)$
                    $G'(x) = F'(b(x))b'(x) = f(b(x))b'(x)$

from above .I not sure it true or false.

Answer (score 2):

True.

$$ G(x) = \int_a^{b(x)} f(t)dt,\ F(x) = \int^x_af(t)dt,\ F'(x) =f(x)$$
by Fundamental theorem of calculus.

Then $G(x)= F(b(x))$ so that $$ G'(x) = F'(b(x))b'(x) = f(b(x))b'(x)$$ by Chain rule.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interested in general with Leibniz's rule which says,

$$\frac{d}{dx} \int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} f(x,t)dt = b'(x)f(x,b(x))-a'(x)f(x,a(x))+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,t)dt.$$

You compute this by letting $F(x,y)=\int_0^y f(x,t)dt$ and using the chain rule to differentiate $F(x,b(x))-F(x,a(x))$.